# Сделать на CSS дугу

Tags: html, css

Как сделать дугу на CSS:

[image: Пример 1]
[image: Пример 2]

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: http://fotohost.by/image/22bI вот еще. Забыл

Comment: Вот [варианты волны](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/) на англоязычном SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, с помощью `border-radius`:

```css
.arc {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 0 0 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="arc"></div>
```